# git-remote-https broken

Tags: git, github, ssh, debian, git-clone

After noticing that my Git distribution would no longer perform basic tasks, such as cloning, I came to the conclusion that my git-remote-https is broken:

```
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~/temp/Vision[]$ GIT_TRACE=2 git fetch
10:44:44.305725 git.c:349               trace: built-in: git 'fetch'
10:44:44.369539 run-command.c:341       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/JasonFil/Vision'
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~/temp/Vision[]$ $(git --exec-path)/git-remote-https
Segmentation fault
```

`git --exec-path` evaluates to:

```
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~/temp/Vision[]$ git --exec-path
/usr/lib/git-core
```

Therefore:

```
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~/temp/Vision[]$ /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https
Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas on how to solve the problem? Here are some system specs (I'm running Debian Testing):

```
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~/OneDrive/code/datasets/Dataset_Cyber$ cd
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~$ git --version
git version 2.1.4
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~$ cat /etc/debian_version 
stretch/sid
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~$ uname -r
3.16.0-4-686-pae
```

**Edit to answer Matthieu's comment on an incompatible version of a library:**

The command in question gives me a variety of information:

```
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~$ ldd $(git --exec-path)/git-remote-https
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xb77be000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb7732000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb7715000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb76fd000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76e1000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb76d8000)
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0xb7659000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xb7630000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7485000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77c1000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0xb7450000)
    librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0xb742f000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1 (0xb7400000)
    libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0xb73c1000)
    libgnutls-deb0.so.28 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls-deb0.so.28 (0xb727b000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0xb722a000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0xb7154000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0xb7120000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0xb711b000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0xb710a000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0xb70b0000)
    libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0xb707b000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0xb6fec000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0xb6f3b000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0xb6ed7000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0xb6ec2000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0xb6eb5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb6eb0000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0xb6eab000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0xb6e8c000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xb6e77000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xb6e6f000)
```

I'm not sure where I should focus first. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `git clone --verbose ...` output?

Comment: Pretty much nothing beyond ordinary clone: `jason@jasonfil-    laptop:~/temp$ git clone --verbose https://github.com/JasonFil/Vision.git
Cloning into 'Vision'...` And the directory is still empty.

Comment: Jason - I would remove all the info in your question except for the segfault, and then start adding things in about the version of Git you have and additional OS details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after re-installation of package `libcurl3`.

Answer (score 4):

`git clone` internally does a `git init` and a `git fetch`. You may get more information by doing these steps manually, like:

```
git init Vision
cd Vision/
git remote add origin https://github.com/JasonFil/Vision
git fetch
git checkout master
```

Another thing to try is:

```
GIT_TRACE=2 git clone --verbose https://github.com/JasonFil/Vision
```

This should be far more verbose that `--verbose` alone.

Comment: After performing the first set of commands, I received the following error message after performing `git checkout master`: `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.` After executing the second command, the following is what I got:

    `10:31:52.807896 git.c:349               trace: built-in: git 'clone' '--verbose' 'https://github.com/JasonFil/Vision'
    Cloning into 'Vision'...
    10:31:52.844314 run-command.c:341       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/JasonFil/Vision'`

Not sure what to make of those more verbose messages.

Comment: The most important is the exact output of `git fetch`.

Comment: Right, that's non-existent. No output whatsoever. I did notice an exit code of 128, though, like so: `jason@jasonfil-laptop:~/temp/Vision[]$ git fetch
jason@jasonfil-laptop:~/temp/Vision[]$ echo $?
128`

Comment: And `GIT_TRACE=2 git fetch`? And `$(git --exec-path)/git-remote-https`?

Comment: I answered in the form of an edit in the original thread, such that I can actually format this somehow. The latter's giving me a Seg Fault....

Comment: OK, then your `git-remote-https` is broken. Your use-case is common enough, so it can't really be a bug in Git (that would be too obvious, everybody would have the same problem), so I would bet for a binary-incompatible version of a library, typically curl. `ldd $(git --exec-path)/git-remote-https` will show you which library is used.

Comment: I have updated the original question such that it gives me the output of that particular command you suggested. Lots of libraries there, any idea which one I should focus on first?

Comment: All libraries use standard path (I was expecting a $HOME/whatever to show up). I don't have more ideas, sorry (well, you can try to use GDB, but I'm not sure it will help). If you're sure it's exactly the binary provided by Debian, you may try to report this as a bug.

Comment: No worries. People elsewhere, eg. [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Re-segfault-in-git-remote-http-td7582133.html) point towards libcurl being the perpetrator. I will focus on that one first.

Comment: Well, whaddya know, I re-installed libcurl3 and it all fixed itself. I will make sure I answer my own question. Thanks.